# How to check php.ini / php settings about crypting (BLOWFISH)

Tags: php, ini, crypt, blowfish

My websites's **user login function suddenly stopped working** on a **rented server( web hosting service)**  ( It worked wonderfully before for YEARS.) Because I didn't changed anything, the database is also untouched (not hacked or altered), i thought maybe something happened with the PHP settings or modules on the server (because it's a rented server  I cannot reach the config files) The server's helpdesk team told me they did nothing / didn't upgrade. (  they don't want to help me solve this. )

As far as I could research the **crypt()** function "stopped working" (gives back *0 instead of the correct hash as before).

I tried to google for information about how to check the server side settings about or state of crypting / BLOWFISH, but I couldn't find anything, so any help is greatly appreciated!

The salt that worked million times before is look like this:

```
$salt=  '$2a$05$2m6Jboi4zN5V2F/bvUCpH$' ;
$hashed_password = crypt($login_password,$salt);
```

It doesn't work with my admin login either ( the login credentials are 100% correct )

The users and admin cannot login, the systems tells them the credentials are wrong, which is caused by the checking /matching of a non-existing hash (*0) produced by the crypt() function. ( $password_hash_from_database !== $hashed_password_provided_by_crypt
)

Server PHP version is **7.3**

Thank you in advance

Comment: stopped working in what way, exactly?

Comment: The users and admin cannot login, the systems tells them the credentials are wrong, which is caused by the checking /matching of a non-existing hash (*0) produced by the crypt() function. ( $password_hash_from_database == $hashed_password_provided_by_crypt    ) fails

Comment: You ought to [edit] your post whenever you have important info such as that. Don't hide it in the comments, put it in context in your post! Also make sure you provide a [mre] of the issue including relevant code. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! I'm not blaming the codes and inputs (because they are worked for years), i just need some help how to get information from php.ini about the current state of the crypt modules or settings that can be ralated to this. Because this way i can check its server sided or not

Comment: Have you tried `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Have you tried `phpinfo();`? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: Salt starting with `$2a$` means it will use the Blowfish algorithm. Not sure if that needs any additional modules or libraries installed, or is just broken in certain PHP versions? -> https://3v4l.org/D25IO

Comment: Regarding CBroe's comment... `Server PHP version is 7.3` ...are you completely sure? Looking at those results from the 3v4l demo, I wonder. You can check with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php

Comment: @ADyson  I've tried php.info but i'm too beginner to understand the meanings/inportance of the data in that. It's PHP Version 7.3.33, System Linux s37. I've deleted some sensitive information from it (hopefully all of them :) ) but here's the whole phpinfo() result: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oguJIdvUmjJO4XF2nGH21oEfNCd2QxxoMDF8HCf0eE0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That link isn't public

Comment: @ADyson Sorry, I've changed it to public.

Comment: Does `crypt` return a hash if you change the last `$` in the salt to any alphabet? According to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php), your current salt is invalid.

Comment: @shingo Thank you! Yes, it gives a hash! But how on earth can it be invalid suddenly if it worked for almost 10 years now for hundreds of users ? I'm flabbergasted.  But now i guess i have a much bigger problem: how can I repair that? I have thousands of users with similar salts ( and pass hashes stored created with these salts .. ) :(

Comment: If you're finding you're in a situation where you need to start again, I'd actually advise, rather than building your own hashing mechanism like this, to learn about PHP's built-in, up-to-date, secure [password hashing and verification functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead. See also [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords). This should also future-proof your code a bit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very sure, but it's probably because of this security patch: [BCrypt hashes erroneously validate if the salt is cut short by `$](https://github.com/php/php-src/security/advisories/GHSA-7fj2-8x79-rjf4). Although the version it mentions does not involve PHP 7, due to this being a security vulnerability and easy to fix, it is estimated that your server administrator has applied this patch to your PHP.

Here's a workaround, use `$2a$05$2m6Jboi4zN5V2F/bvUCp..` instead of your salt. You will obtain the same encryption result, <s>then to replace the salt part in the result with `$2a$05$2m6Jboi4zN5V2F/bvUCpH.`.</s> then to compare the hashed results except for the first 29 characters.

```
$salt2 = '$2a$05$2m6Jboi4zN5V2F/bvUCp..';
$hashed_password = crypt($login_password, $salt2);
if(substr($hashed_password, 29) === substr($hashed_password_indb, 29))
...
```

---

Explanation to the workaround.

The last `$` in your old salt `$2a$05$2m6Jboi4zN5V2F/bvUCpH$` is not a valid character, according the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php), the valid characters are `./0-9A-Za-z`.

The blowfish algorithm in PHP will convert the last 22 characters of the salt into 4 ints in groups of 4 characters (check the [source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/2740920a392c043b034e2f0e41d819549836712a/ext/standard/crypt_blowfish.c#L388))

Because of the vulnerability, the last `$` and the preceding `H` are actually discarded, and these two bytes will be treated as 0 in actual calculations (`.` is the first valid character, so it will be treated as 0). If `$` is in another position, there are more digits to be discarded. You can check the following example for comparison:

```
$login_password = '123345345SDFHSD3453';
$salt1 = '$2a$05$2m6Jboi4zN5V2F/$vUCpH8';
$salt2 = '$2a$05$2m6Jboi4zN5V2F........';
$hashed_password1 = crypt($login_password, $salt1);
$hashed_password2 = crypt($login_password, $salt2);

# $hashed_password1 & $hashed_password2:
# $2a$05$2m6Jboi4zN5V2F/$vUCpHu4CWNoXuc3r8QkJHciPMdM3J.4y2lS.S
# $2a$05$2m6Jboi4zN5V2F........4CWNoXuc3r8QkJHciPMdM3J.4y2lS.S
```

The first 29 characters are the salt, so it's not necessary to take care of them.

Comment: Thank you so much, it looks super promising! Only thing is: it gives 500 internal server error  ( the number 1 in str_replace needs to be passed as a reference/variable  ), and unfortunatelly this does not work for me so maybe i've misunderstood your solution. So for $salt2 i need to cut 2 digits off from the right side of the salt, and for $saltr I need to cut 1 digit from the right, right? (Then add extra dots, 1 for the second, 2 for the first)

Comment: That's right, number 1 is not necessary here, I just want to ensure it won't be replaced more than once.

Comment: Wait, not quite right if you have a different salt, I'll make an explanation in detail.

Comment: Please check my update. The bytes to be discarded is related to the position of `$`, and you need to calculate it.

Comment: Thank you so much, you've literally saved my life! I cannot thank you enough (it worked wonderfully). Fortunately all of our generated salts are same length